# How do I detect whether DNS servers have been specified programmatically in .net?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, dns, windows-networking

How can I programmatically detect whether DNS servers are explicitly defined in windows 7:

[image]

Static ip addressing can be identified using `IPv4InterfaceProperties::IsDhcpEnabled` but I can't find a similar setting for the dns.

I've tried `IPInterfaceProperties::IsDnsEnabled` and `IPInterfaceProperties::IsDynamicDnsEnabled` but neither of those appear to change when I alter the setting via the windows dialog.

I need to get this information so that I can perform some setup / tear down for a unit test I'm writing.

I've also tried `IPInterfaceProperties::DnsAddresses`. This lists the addresses as statically specified or if none are specified it appears to pick them up from my network (we have DHCP and DNS servers running). I don't want to explicitely set DNS servers in the teardown method if it was previously configured to do it dynamically.

Comment: Um. Why would a *unit* test include testing the network code of windows? I understand that it's reasonably robust, and has probably already been tested...

Comment: We're not trying to test whether Windows networking commands work. We have an embedded device and we use these commands to change the device's IP address when it first boots or if a user requests it. The unit tests are verifying that the code we wrap around the windows networking calls is working. So if a user requests a change to a new IP address, we need to be certain that it takes.

Comment: You are not going to get this info out of a .NET call.  IsDynamicDnsEnabled means something else.  I don't understand the relevance either, just having the addresses (either way) doesn't say anything at all about whether they are correct.  Simply try to resolve an named address to check if the DNS setup is correct.

Comment: It's not about whether they're correct; I just want to leave the dev / test machine running the code in the same configuration the test code found it in. This won't be the same for all machines and some but not all will specify one or more dns servers.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not a pure .net solution, but if we run:

```
netsh -c interface dump > current_network_settings.txt
```

before the test and:

```
netsh -f current_network_settings.txt
```

after the tests have executed, we should be back to where we started.